# Pulling values from a List on a .JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I've got a list of totalHours which contains this:

```
{Meeting Hours=2.5, Non-Billable Hours=0.0, Administration Hours=5.5, Shipping Hours=0.0, Travel Hours=1.25, Programming Hours=7.5, Research Hours=0.0}
```

I want to send the list as an attribute to the JSP page from a Servlet and display only the numeric values.

What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: try coding something, always a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JSTL foreach tag to iterate over the array and print out what you need.

Here is an example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:forEach> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

source : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

If you have any further, more specific questions about how to use it, try writing some code then post here.